# Rails 3 - Comments/Message - "\n\r"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

In my application I have places where users can send messages and leave comments on content. So to keep this simple, I have Comment, with and id (integer) and body (text).

When printing these in HTML, I want the user's formatting, for example a comment might be entered like this:

> comment added
>
> with an enter

In the database, this comes to be:

```
comment.body.last
"comment added\r\n\r\nwith an enter"
```

On my page then, this comes to simple look like "comment added with an enter". What I'm wondering is if there is a way in my view to let it know I want to render these enter characters? As 
's or something? Does anyone know how to preserve the user's format?

Thanks a ton guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) will format text in the way you are describing. It's built in to Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Use `simple_format`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

```
<%= simple_format(your_string_variable) %>
```